# using excel, query SQL for specific tags in a table for a given date range

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access

using excel 2013 I need to create a search of a SQL tbl on network SQL server for a specific tag and within a given date range.  for instance: the tbl has every make of Chevy made since 1990 and the units sold each day. an example, search for corvette with a date range of 1Jul2017 to 31Jul2017.  the result would show up how many corvettes were sold for each day in July of 2017 and I will need to have the total sold for entire month of July.

this in important: I only want them to access the data NOT be able to make changes to database

I can do this in SQL no problem, but I have to do this so someone who does not have access to the SQL database can use this query and get the information they need. the eventual goal is to have an Access frontend for this.

edit: I am no expert in either Excel or SQL but know enough to get some things done. one of the many hats I wear . . .

thanks,

Comment: When you create a connection to SQL Server, you could provide your SQL in the properties window. Have you checked this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-excel

Comment: Write your SQL query. Make it into a view. Create a SQL login that has only read access to that view alone. Create a data connection in Excel for the user. Give the user the credentials and show them how to refresh the data. Now the user has access to only this data via Excel.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, **Data** tab, **New Query**, **From Database**, pick the type of database, add connection info, click **Advanced options**, put your query in the **SQL statement** window, hit **OK**, hit **Load**.  Now you have SQL results in a spreadsheet.  If you want them to update regularly, go to **Data** tab again, **Connections**, select the connection you just made from the list, click **Properties**, and set it to refresh every hour, or when opening the file, or whatever makes sense to you.

This will only work for users that have permissions to the database.  If you need it to be more secure (not hold data in the spreadsheet at all, but only access it from the database), in the connections properties click **Refresh data when opening the file**, then click **Remove data from the external data range before saving the workbook**.

Comment: thank you for the reply.  I forgot to add I have Office 2013 and the SQL datatbase is on a network SQL server. I have edited my original post to reflect this.

I do not have "New Query" on my data tab in Excel, it could be my version 2013

Comment: Then in the Data tab, you have **From Other Sources** or **From ODBC** or something like that.  Same idea, slightly different steps. SQL from Excel has been in the tool since long before 2013, so you just need to adapt these directions; this concept will work.